# How to insert date in laravel Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am using Code in Controller :-

```
$leave = new Leavemodel();
$leave->leave_startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('startdate')));
$leave->leave_enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('startdate')));
$leave->leave_notify = 0;
$leave->leave_reasone = $request->input('reason');
$leave->leave_notify = 0;
$leave->save();
return Redirect::back();
```

I have This Type of error:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qohro.png)

Comment: isset($request->input('startdate'))?date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('startdate'))) :null;

Comment: but i get Val of date in $request->input('startdate') @iCoders

Comment: Use Carbon Same Error @iCoders

Comment: can you show dd($request->all()); printed values

Comment: array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "cUqpwpw414bFPbcIit8oK9hJG07KDX8qOKGo1D3h"
  "startdate" => "07/11/2020"
  "enddate" => "15/11/2020"
  "reason" => "<h2 style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: DauphinPlain; font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px; color: rgb(0,  ▶"
  "files" => null
]

Comment: always validate your input before saving it in your database. What would happen here if fields are missing or (even worse) they are not the type you expect?

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images, post it as text. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'startdate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
                'enddate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
                'reason' => 'required|min:20',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
    }
    $date_start = $request->input('startdate');
    $date2_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_start);
    $date3_start = $date2_start->format("Y-m-d");
    $date_end = $request->input('enddate');
    $date2_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_end);
    $date3_ens = $date2_end->format("Y-m-d");

    $leave = new Leavemodel();
    $leave->leave_startdate = $date3_start;
    $leave->leave_enddate = $date3_ens;
    $leave->leave_notify = 0;
    $leave->leave_reasone = $request->input('reason');
    $leave->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to format string date before converting to stringtotime

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$request->input('startdate'))))
```

if you are using Carbon then

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('startdate'));
dd($date->toDateString());
```

**Update :**
To Avoid error,validate data before inserting

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
      'startdate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
         'enddate' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
  ]);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
  }
  
$leave = new Leavemodel();
$leave->leave_startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('startdate')));
$leave->leave_enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('startdate')));
$leave->leave_notify = 0;
$leave->leave_reasone = $request->input('reason');
$leave->leave_notify = 0;
$leave->save();
return Redirect::back();
```

Comment: GETTING :-  The separation symbol could not be found
 Unexpected data found.
 Trailing data  @iCoders

Comment: @for Carbon code then check format from $request->input('startdate') is proper one i mean 10/11/2020 similar like this

Comment: add validation to check date format  to avoid this issue.may be start date is empty or format is different

Comment: Steal i getting Creating default object from empty value @iCoders

Comment: can you show full model class

Comment: Creating default object from empty value @iCoders

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Leavemodel extends Model {

    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'Leave';
    protected $fillable = ['leave_startdate', 'leave_enddate', 'leave_reasone', 'leave_notify'];

}
@iCoders

Comment: for testing purpose just harcode value like this for both date field date('Y-m-d', strtotime("15/10/2020"))

Comment: Still i Getting :- Creating default object from empty value @iCoders

Comment: look like other fields are passing empty.for example leave_reasone.try to hardcode leave_reasone value also

Comment: Still Get same error @iCoders You use Teamviewer My id = 1 192 499 717 pass: vpm217 Plz

Comment: i'm stuck of this error

Comment: Store in databse Like Y-d-m @iCoders

Comment: share code in github.i iwll check

Answer (score 0):

**model set $fillable or $guarded ;**

```
protected $fillable = [
 'leave_startdate','leave_enddate',
 'leave_notify','leave_reasone','leave_notify'
 ]
```

If you do not have timestamps, set the following value to false in the database

```
public $timestamps  = false
```

controller store

```
return Redirect::back();

Leavemodel::craete([
'leave_startdate ' => Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('startdate')),
'leave_enddate' =>  Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('startdate')),
'leave_notify' => 0,
'leave_reasone' => $request->input('reason'),
'leave_notify' => 0,
]);
```